# Replace properties with it's values in pom.xml before putting the pom file into maven repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml

**When installing the project into (local) maven repository, I would like to replace all properties placeholders with their current actual values, is this somehow possible?**

All in all I'm trying to create a customizable project version in maven, in order to resolve some problems with the transitive dependencies.

Here is my minimized pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>T</artifactId>
<version>${custom.version}</version>

<properties>
    <custom.version>TEST</custom.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>pom.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${basedir}</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

After "mvn clean install" I would like to have in the local maven repository here "~/.m2/repository/com/foo/T/TEST/T-Test.pom" following contents:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>T</artifactId>
<version>TEST</version>

<properties>
    <custom.version>TEST</custom.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>doesn't matter</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>pom.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>doesn't matter</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

So the ${custom.version} placeholder should be replaced by it's current value "TEST", before installing the project into maven repository.

But all I get - is an empty file, even in the current project directory, probably because the file is locked and maven can't override it.

**Is there any possibility to install/deploy the pom file with resolved property values?**

Comment: What problem do you try to resolve.
Taking project version from properties is not good behavior. Each build should produce the same application and should be reproduced on any system without special configurations.

Comment: I have to build for different platforms, therefore the version should be different.

Comment: In such cases a classifier would be the right choice and not the version.

Answer (score 5):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>T</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>${custom.version}</version>

<properties>
    <custom.version>TEST2</custom.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>./</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pomFile>target/pom.xml</pomFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Produces in "~/.m2/repository/com/foo/T/TEST/T-Test.pom" what I want.