# How to store the released version of a project in a specific property?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

We have a build scenario that has turned out to be too complex for Maven and maven-release-plugin and I'm at the end of my wits.

My team deals with a portfolio of applications that all use a multimodule Java library (called "dev-stack") and all (including the library) had the same parent (called "super-pom").

In order to solve the problem of the same dependency being used in different versions throughout the portfolio, I transformed the super-pom into a BOM, with all dependencies expressed in a `<dependencyManagement>` section. This has the benefit of defining the versions of each and any dependency (including the modules of the library) once and for all. There are other benefits, but they are irrelevant to this question that I'm asking.

The super-pom follows the tradition of other BOMs out there by specifying versions using properties. For instance,

```
<jackson-version>2.12.0</jackson-version>
```

There is therefore such a property for the library:

```
<dev-stack-version>${project.version}</dev-stack-version>
```

Due to a cumbersome release process, we've decided to merge the super-pom into the library, which will then become the parent of all applications.

A dependency to the library module looks like this:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.delfingen</groupId>
        <artifactId>dev-stack-batch</artifactId>
        <version>${dev-stack-version}</version><!-- problematic version specification --> 
      </dependency>
```

maven-release-plugin fails to build the library if the version specified in a dependency is neither `${project.version}` nor a direct version value such as `2.0.0` nor a property that resolves to one of the previous two possibilities. The error message is:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project dev-stack: The artifact (com.delfingen:dev-stack-batch) requires a different version (2.0.0) than what is found (${project.version}) for the expression (dev-stack-version) in the project (com.delfingen:dev-stack)

I can't understand why maven-release-plugin cannot interpolate the expression (dev-stack-version) and determine that it actually matches the required version (2.0.0).

Anyway, my problem is that:

- If I specify `${project.version}`, the library builds fine and maven-release-plugin performs the release without any problems, but then, none of the applications based on the library will build, because the dependency version `${project.version}` gets evaluated when the application is built, which yields the version of the application, not that of the library. There is [a JIRA entry](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5900) that covers exactly this issue.
- I just cannot specify a direct version number as this is the version number that maven-release-plugin will define and I don't know it. If I set it beforehand, then Maven fails to find the dependency as it is not built yet.

After many days of trials, my need is to decouple the version of the library from the version of the application that uses the library both as a dependency and as a parent.

Is it possible to make maven-plugin-version update the value of a property (namely, 'dev-stack-version' in my case) to the final release version of the project it has operated on?

Or is there some obvious solution that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Not sure if this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308600/replace-properties-with-its-values-in-pom-xml-before-putting-the-pom-file-into

Comment: It is indeed related, just the other way around: they want the property value to be put in the project version and I want the reverse. I've kept reflecting on my issue and I'm starting to think that only Maven 4 could solve it.